# Echo the command result in a file.txt

Tags: bash, echo

I have a script such as :

```
cat list_id.txt | while read line; do for ACC in $line;
do
    echo -n "$ACC\t"
    curl -s "link=fasta&retmode=xml" |\
    grep TSeq_taxid |\
    cut -d '>' -f 2 |\
    cut -d '<' -f 1 |\
    tr -d "\n"
    echo 
sleep 0.25
done
done
```

This script allows me from a list of ID in `list_id.txt` to get the corresponding names in a database in `https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/efetch.fcgi?db=nuccore&id=${ACC}&rettype=fasta&retmode=xml`

So from this script I get something like

```
CAA42669\t9913
V00181\t7154
AH002406\t538120
```

And what I would like is directly to print or echo this result in fiel call `new_ids.txt`, I tried `echo >> new_ids.txt` but the file is empty.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try replacing the lines 8 and 9 with this: `tr -d "\n" | cat > new_ids.txt`

Comment: @Alimo No need for `cat`. `tr -d "\n" > new_ids.txt` will do the same. Anyways, it would be better to place the redirection after the loop. @bean Simply add `> new_ids.txt` at the end of the line of the last `done`.

Comment: Thank you for your help

Comment: The backslashes aren't necessary after a line-final `|`. A command cannot end with a pipe, so the shell knows to continue reading from the next line.

Answer (score 0):

A minimal refactoring of your script might look like

```
# Avoid useless use of cat
# Use read -r
# Don't use upper case for private variables
while read -r line; do
  for acc in $line; do
    echo -n "$acc\t"
    # No backslash necessary after | character
    curl -s "link=fasta&retmode=xml" |
    # Probably use a proper XML parser for this
    grep TSeq_taxid |
    cut -d '>' -f 2 |
    cut -d '<' -f 1 |
    tr -d "\n"
    echo
    sleep 0.25
  done
done <list_id.txt >new_ids.txt
```

This could probably still be simplified significantly, but without knowledge of what your input file looks like exactly, or what `curl` returns, this is somewhat speculative.

```
tr -s ' \t\n' '\n' <list_id.txt |
while read -r acc; do
    curl -s "link=fasta&retmode=xml" |
    awk -v acc="$acc" '/TSeq_taxid/ {
        split($0, a, /[<>]/); print acc "\t" a[3] }'
    sleep 0.25
done <list_id.txt >new_ids.txt
```